# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) in rails when attempting to import .csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to import a .csv to refill and complete many forms, rather than having to fill and create them one by one. I've followed a pretty nifty tutorial here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8pohTautj8 which has been really helpful. I then tweaked it for nested resources by this post here: https://gorails.com/forum/import-a-csv-with-associations

So far so good. I then made a few final tweaks to get where I was having issues with Authenticity tokens, NilClass errors and now I'm getting wrong number of arguments. All the stack overflow posts that also present this error that I've seen haven't been able to help.

Here's the code:

**controller**

```
def create
    @development = Development.find(params[:development_id])
    @lot = @development.lots.create(params.require[:lot].permit(:status, :lot_number ,:stage, :land_size, :price, :bed, :bath, :car, :rent))
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lot.save
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to Development.find(params[:development_id]), notice: "Lot was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lot }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @lot.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end 

def import
    @development = Development.find(params[:development_id])
    @lot = @development.lots.create(params.require[:lot].permit(:status, :lot_number ,:stage, :land_size, :price, :bed, :bath, :car, :rent))
    Lot.import(@development, development_params[:lot])
    redirect_to development_path, notice: "Lots were successfully created."
  end
```

**model**

```
  def self.import(development, file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        development.lots.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

**_form partial**

```
<%= form_tag import_development_lots_path, multipart: true, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do %>
                <%= file_field_tag :file %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
                <%= submit_tag "Upload csv" %>
                <% end %>
```

**Note:** This is additional to the regular, original form (both on the same _form partial) to create the object. It was my understanding that the original could stay as a means of creating data tables manually, one at a time, as another option to the mass csv import option. Please let me know if I need to add the code for the original form too. They seem to be fine to coexist on the same page together.

**routes**

```
resources :lots do
      collection { post :import }
      end
```

**application.rb**

```
require 'csv'
```

I believe that's everything related to the csv import; any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
Here's the error log as requested by Siim.

```
Started POST "/developments/2/lots" for ::1 at 2021-05-13 10:46:14 +1000
Processing by LotsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"s7EpVu4LymhZpm+nSxGF+yLXWY3GqHjwKSN0eccRCws7eTy1riGg9GplIciLIns7hlKYyRipA5tgMbGn0GTGow==", "file"=>"Test Lot.csv", "commit"=>"Upload Stocklist", "development_id"=>"2"}
  Development Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "developments".* FROM "developments" WHERE "developments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lots_controller.rb:71:in `get_development'
  CACHE Development Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "developments".* FROM "developments" WHERE "developments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/lots_controller.rb:25:in `create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms | Allocations: 1798)



ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):

app/controllers/lots_controller.rb:26:in `create'
```

Comment: Add your error and it's backtrace so we can see where the error is coming from and what method is receiveing wrong arguments.

Comment: @SiimLiiser updated with the error log. Let me know if you need to see anything else!

Comment: Error is saying the mistake is on line 26 in the controller. But you only pasted a snippet so I don't know which line that is.

Comment: Ah right, that would be this line here:

@lot = @development.lots.create(params.require[:lot].permit(:status, :lot_number ,:stage, :land_size, :price, :bed, :bath, :car, :rent))

It's nested and works fine, but I recently changed it from params to params.require

Comment: I'd originally changed it to include .require because I was getting a NilClass error for 'permit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error backtrace (from comments), the error is on the following line:

```
@lot = @development.lots.create(params.require[:lot].permit(:status, :lot_number ,:stage, :land_size, :price, :bed, :bath, :car, :rent))
```

If you would break that apart to multiple lines you would get an even more accurate error message to find it out yourself, but I can already see it.

`require` is a method that requires an argument. You are calling it without arguments and then accessing it as an array/hash by calling `[]` on it.

Use `params.require(:lot)` instead of `params.require[:lot]`.

Comment: Hi Siim, thanks for this one! Turns out this issue was a smaller part of a much larger one. I was able to sort out the whole issue by following this article: http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/csv and re-structuring my csv upload to come from the index page rather than the pre-existing form for manual data entry.